# Gateway Keeps Resetting to Old Gateway

Tags: raspbian, networking

I'm not that familiar with Linux but I'm running a pi-hole. I've just changed my network config on my router (Draytek) that supports VLANS and interlan routing. I have the PI on its own VLAN (2) LAN 3, I have set the interlan routing so that it's accessible on VLAN1, 2 and 3. VLAN 1 (LAN 2) is a VPN VLAN that is isolated from VLAN 0 (LAN1) (internal clients).

So when I made these changes I no longer had internet and it took me a while to realize this was due to the pi-hole not being able to parse DNS requests. Even though I reset the PI and re-configured it for the new gateway for that VLAN (192.168.3.1) it still had the former gateway in ifconfig. The problem is, whenever I reset pi-hole or manually add the 192.168.3.1 gateway it simply disappears after a while and it loses internet and DNS parsing. When this route is removed it's affectively isolated the pi-hole from any other subnet and wan.

What am I missing here? Why does the pi-hole keep reverting its gateway to 192.168.1.1 and/or removing the 192.168.3.1 route?

I can't think of a reason it's doing (doesn't even seem to be when rebooting, came home today and it's lost its gateway I set up earlier).

*Resolved* Found historic static address information in /etc/dhcpcd.conf - editted it out and retained the correct one which resolved the issue (tested through reboots).

Comment: I do not understand the setup from your description. Can you please provide a simple drawing what subnet (VLAN) is used for what how are they connected together?

Comment: VLAN 0 is for internal clients, 192.168.1.0/24.
VLAN 1 is for VPN traffic (router has a VPN server).
VLAN 2 is for the pi-hole exclusively.
Routing is enabled for VLAN 2 so that it can communicate on all 3 LANS (so that is can act as a DNS server for the entire network.
Routing is disabled for VLAN 0 and 1 so that VPN traffic is isolated from internal clients.
When I change the gateway on the PI everything works. After a while (perhaps reboot), it reverts back to it's old gateway address in ifconfig and nothing works because it's trying to contact the wrong gateway but it keeps its new IP

Comment: And I'm not sure why buy I am paragraphing, this website or browser is truncating the text into one wall of text, not sure why.

Comment: VLAN 0 = 192.168.1.0/24
VLAN 1 = 192.168.2.0/24
VLAN 2 = 192.168.3.0/24

The issue isn't with the VLANS, it's with PI/Raspbian not retaining it's new gateway entry.